# Icons required to submission?

Tags: objective-c

I know, that this subject was discussed here so many times, but i couldn't find a specific answer.
I can see on apple docs that you need all the icons for all devices .
Our app is for iPhones only . so i have 57x57 and 114x114 .
Do i have to set also the other icons such as 72 ? i couldn't find a clear answer for that .

according to this- i dont need . is that right ?
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didnt when I uploaded my Iphone-only app. Just make sure your app is set to target "Iphone" and not "Universal" in xcode.

Answer (score 4):

You need to look here: [Custom Icon and Image Creation Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html)

You'll need:

57x57

114x114

512x512

1024x1024

iPad icons are not needed for an iPhone app.